# Google Map on Android BLANK PAGE (white)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Am trying to dispaly a basic google map on my application but that's not working it display a white screen instead even though I have a net connection also I check my MANEFIST a hundred times and I genrated a deubg key and am sure it is true

I would like if anyone could lead me what am doing wrong ?

I also haven't modified the code but for a second on the EMULATOR the map diplayed and disappeared and on my device it doesn't AT ALL suddenly it doesn't display AT ALL on the emulator.


`public class MyMapDisplayActivity extends MapActivity {`

```
MapController MControl;
GeoPoint GeoP;
MapView mapview;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            //Map
            MapView mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
             mapview.displayZoomControls(true);
             mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

             double lat = 19.7888;
             double longi = 52.535;


             GeoP = new GeoPoint ((int) (lat *1E6),(int) (longi *1E6));


             MControl = mapview.getController();
             MControl.animateTo(GeoP);
             MControl.setZoom(14);




             MyLocationOverlay LocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapview);
             mapview.getOverlays().add(LocationOverlay);
             LocationOverlay.enableCompass();
             LocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
}//onCreate

//Map
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
return false;
}
```

```
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="60px"
         >
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0jiwJEbT6if6dhaf0x6Fr_zRLsrz_CYxcLGj6pQ"
                 />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="jdisplay.map"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".BatteryprojectActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: could you post your manifest, your layout and the Activity code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create two different API keys, one with the debug signing key for the emulator and one with the key you use to sign the apk for the device.

Comment: I already have two different keys.
I just posted the API debug key in the main.xml

Comment: Just saying as it wasn't clear from your question. another thing: it's better to do the enablemylocation in the onResume method and do a disableMyLocation in the onPause method.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to change wrap_content for fill_parent in the LinearLayout's layout_height.

Comment: I did that but I still can't get my map to dispaly.

Comment: Sorry. I can't see what's wrong. Everything else looks Ok, there must be something else...

Comment: The only thing that I can see is that you have declared BatteryprojectActivity in your manifest but your activity class is MyMapDisplayActivity (It could be wrong in the post but ok in your code...) Anything else seems to be right as Carles stated previously. Nevertheless I would double check that the api key is the correct one.

Comment: oh that's my mistake its not in the actual code and thanks am gonna check my key once again I hope that's the problem . . .

Answer (score 0):

I think these two points might help you. I had a similar problem-

1. Try putting the uses-library line just after the application tag and before the activity tag. This matters may be as the library is being referred in the Activity class.
2. If this doesn't fix the issue, try to check if your API Key was generated correctly.Locate the SDK debug certificate located in the default folder of "C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Android" and use this location path in the Keytool command. You can also copy it to "C:\android" and then run 
   'keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android'. Either ways the path needs to be correctly specified. It does create the key anyway but doesn't load the map when running the app. My map loaded in a jiffy after I re-created the key correclty.

Answer (score 0):

**Debug key** - You can use it to debug your app directly from Android Studio or Eclipse with google map api on your virtual device or your phone/tablet via USB.

**Release key** - You can use it to make a signed apk file which you can install it on any other device.

If you want to test your release key you need to create apk file of your app and install it on your device - trust me it is 100% sure !!!

**You can't use a release key for debugging(running map) apps !!!**

That's why it's called Debug and Release :D