# How to show the route from current location to already stored destination in map using polyline without needing to click the map to set destination

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

This is my `MainActivity` from which it doesn't show up route automatically at map load until I tap the destination. I want it to make the route would appear from current location to destination on its start.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> mMarkerPoints;
double mLatitude=27.7247789;
double mLongitude=85.320704;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Initializing
        mMarkerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        mGoogleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already map contain destination location
                if(mMarkerPoints.size()>1){

                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    mMarkerPoints.clear();
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                    drawMarker(startPoint);
                }

                drawMarker(point);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(mMarkerPoints.size() >= 2){
                    LatLng origin = mMarkerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = mMarkerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}



/** A class to download data from Google Directions URL */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Directions in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(2);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
    mMarkerPoints.add(point);

    // Creating MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting the position of the marker
    options.position(point);

    /**
     * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
     * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
     */
    if(mMarkerPoints.size()==1){
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    }else if(mMarkerPoints.size()==2){
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    }

    // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Draw the marker, if destination location is not set
    if(mMarkerPoints.size() < 2){

        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));


        drawMarker(point);
    }

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Handler** for this purpose. In the location update request, you mentioned the time interval as 20000 ms(20 seconds). So, we can run the handler after 40 seconds (approximately). The code will be changed to

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Already map contain destination location
            if(mMarkerPoints.size()>1){

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                mMarkerPoints.clear();
                mGoogleMap.clear();
                LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                drawMarker(startPoint);
            }

            drawMarker(point);

            // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
            if(mMarkerPoints.size() >= 2){
                LatLng origin = mMarkerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = mMarkerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);
            }               
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 40000);
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for help. I appreciate it a lot.. I will try to implement it. Thank you once again :)

Comment: When I run my program it only shows white space over the fragment alongwith GPS location button on top right and 'Google' trademark at the bottom left :( what might be the problem?? I have latest version of Google play services.

Comment: Check your google API key. Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015144/google-map-on-android-blank-page-white?rq=1

Comment: Yeah I have checked my google API key, Manifest file, but I can't seem to find error there... Does it have to do anything with my Android Version on my Genymotion emulator? My app's minm sdk version = 15..

Comment: Please check your debug keystore file